# How to check if date is in the future for separate date and time columns?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-10

I have 2 separate columns for the date: the `date` itself in `YYYY-mm-dd` format, and a `time` column in `time(7)` datatype, for example `11:15:10.0000000`

How can I check for rows that are in the future?

I can get the first part, for the day itself:

```
MyModel::where('date', '>=', Carbon::today())->get()
```

But when I try adding the time it doesn't work:

```
MyModel::where('date', '>=', Carbon::today())->where('time', '>', Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))->get()
```

because they are separate and now even though the date is in the future, the time is separate so there may be a situation where the time doesn't match. So I somehow need to have both the date and the time related to it in the future, not separately

Comment: Why have you got separate columns in the first place?

Comment: Because in reality it's a record that represents an event that occurs in a specific date between 2 hours: i.e. at 24-08-2023 between 08:00 and 10:00. I am not in charge of the database but I admit it's weird and I should probably tell him to change, instead of 3 columns - date, start time and end time, to start datetime and end datetime, right?

Comment: Yes that would be much easier to work with, in various ways

Comment: Your current structure probably doesn't deal well with events that happen between 23:00 and 01:00. Maybe that's not a real scenario in your situation, but a change of structure would handle that as well.

Comment: Answers that come down to "date > current date OR time > current time" will return you all the past events that happened later in their day than it is right now. You need "date > current date OR (date = current date AND time > current time)".

Comment: @GregSchmidt you are correct, and the query you suggested is what I use and is working (If you notice nice_dev's answer it's what I use which is your query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison via datatype is important here. So, you can use `orWhere` to combine 2 different conditions. For this, you will need to pass a callback to group conditions inside one for the *AND* in where conditions in raw format.

```
<?php

MyModel::where('date', '>', Carbon::today())
        ->orWhere(function($query){
            $query->where('date', '=', Carbon::today())
                  ->where('time', '>', Carbon::now()->format('H:i'));
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine both the columns in a single condition.

```
$now = Carbon::now();

MyModel::whereRaw("CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`) >= ?", [$now->toDateTimeString()])->get();
```

For SQL Server try following

```
MyModel::whereRaw("CONVERT(datetime, date + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, time, 121)) >= ?", [$now->toDateTimeString()])->get();
```

Query conversion may need to update, for more information try [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: thanks, the query is successful, however it returns all the rows, even the past ones from some reason. Maybe it has something to do with the mismatching data types? I am using SQL Server

Comment: Beware of performance whenever you run a query that needs to transform columns in every table row before being able to apply a filter, since it prevents using indexes.